# Android manifest error after adding a service

Tags: android, flutter

So I've been getting an error since I added a service block to AndroidManifest file, have a look at my manifest.

The error says:

> "Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during
> installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1643630122.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML
> file line #42): com.example.shoutout.MainActivity: Targeting S+
> (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for
> android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]"

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shoutout">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
   <application
        android:label="shoutout"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <service android:name="com.example.shoutout.backgroundService"
         android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.app.START_BACKGROUND" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with service or adding a service. Read the message: An exported flag is missing at your activity with an intent-filter.

Answer (score 0):

The errors say You need to add `android:exported="true"` to your activity since you have intent filters present

Try this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true"> // add android:exported here
```